# How do I compute Rq facorization using qr python library

Tags: image-processing, camera-calibration, calibration

I wrote the following code to perform rq decomposition of A metric using qr factorization. I need to get the following matrix where the element A33 is one. How do I need to perform proper normalization to get 1 in that element?

I need this for extracting camera parameters in computer vision.

https://ibb.co/fvk9yrf

Here is my code :

```
    import numpy as np
    
    def rq(M):
        Q, R = np.linalg.qr(np.flipud(M).T)
    
        R = np.flipud(R.T)
        R = np.fliplr(R)
    
        Q = Q.T
        Q = np.flipud(Q)
    
        return R, Q
    
    
    A = A = np.array([
        [707, 679.2, 555.4],
        [207, 46.6, 919.2],
        [1.4, -0.7, 1.22]
    ])
    
    K, R = rq(A)
```